# How do I prevent webpack from rewriting import() so that I can use the buildIn one?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am writing a kind of meta application. It is written in React and bundled by webpack. The meta application loads a .js file based on the user input etc. The .js file may not exist at the bundling time. My loading function should just make an HTTP(S) request, try to load the file, and take a function with a known name in the file.

If I just have `import(aConstructedPath})` in my loading function, webpack treats it as its directive and generates something like `__webpack_require__("./ lazy recursive ^.*$")...`. How can just just say that this `import()` should use the built-in one?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have defined import already. But you can give it a try if you have

```
const anyName = eval(`import(${aConstructedPath})`);
```

Where anyName is imported package.

This will make webpack not to rename the code inside ``

Comment: Yes. wrapping it in eval() does the trick, and it probably is the easiest. Thanks!  I could fetch the file itself and eval it but this probably is more reasonable.

Comment: You can upvote and accept it as answer if you like. Thanks

Comment: I want to do so... but I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote.

Comment: You can accept it as answer, i think that is possible